# Строка в таблице БД

Tags: база-данных

Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Поле `price smallint(7)` таблицы в БД должно быть значение 2800000. 
Нажимаю Редактировать ставлю сумму 2800000 нажимаю "OK" 
На месте суммы 2800000 появляется сумма 32767. 
Что за чудеса такие? Может кто-то встречался или знает ответ?
Почему происходит какой-то непонятный перевод суммы?

```
Поле    Тип Функция Null    Значение

id   int(11) unsigned           
member_id    int(11) unsigned           
brand_id     int(11) unsigned           
model_id     int(11) unsigned           
version  varchar(30)            
car_number   varchar(15)            
vin  varchar(20)            
body     smallint(2)            
gear     smallint(2)            
drive    smallint(2)            
doors    smallint(2)            
color    smallint(2)            
year_made    smallint(4)            
fuel     smallint(2)            
volume   float          
maintenance  smallint(1) unsigned           
exploitation_start   date             
mileage  int(7) unsigned            
mileage_last_update  datetime             
**price  smallint(7)**   **2800000**        
currency     varchar(3)         
comments     text           
date_post    datetime             
code     varchar(32)
```

Comment: @Serg1234 вам не приходило в голову, почему MS SQL (а речь, я так понимаю, о нем) есть целая куча типов для целочисленных значений? int, bigint, smallint, tinyint. Поинтересуйтесь на этот счет, узнаете много нового, в том числе и ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: Ну зачем же сразу минусы ставить. Нужно дать человеку разобраться...

Comment: минусы мешают вам разобраться? Сомневаюсь. Более того, ответ пользователя @tehead и мой комментарий все объясняют по вашему вопросу. А то, что вопрос был совершенно поверхностный - за то и минус

Comment: из раздела чудес в с++
int a = 1/2;

Comment: @ЫЫЫ А причём тут чудеса c++? Нолик там получался задолго до C++. И даже задолго до C (в fortran'е)

Comment: А притом, что на хэшкоде надо создать раздел чудеса. И впихивать туда вот такие вопросы. Классный раздел получится.

Comment: @ЫЫЫ Боюсь в этот раздел будет попадать большинство вопросов =)

Answer (score 1):

Мб потому, что smallint от -32768 до 32767? :)

Comment: Делаю вывод поставить для 8-значных цифр поставить INT или BIGINT?

Тип Байт От До
TINYINT 1 -128 127
SMALLINT 2 -32768 32767
MEDIUMINT 3 -8388608 8388607
INT 4 -2147483648 2147483647
BIGINT 8 -9223372036854775808 9223372036854775807

Comment: int за глаза будет